# Micronaut API and Client with Controller consuming Protobuf

Tags: arrays, rest, controller, protocol-buffers, micronaut

I have a Micronaut @Controller as follows:

```
@Post("/whatever")
@Consumes("application/x-protobuf")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public HttpResponse deserializeData (@Body byte[] body)
        throws ProtobufParsingException {

    return requestHandler.processDataRequest(body);
}
```

and a Client that calls this API:

```
@Client("${protobuf-manager.url}")
public interface ProtobufManagerClient {

@Post("/${protobuf-manager.apiversion}/whatever")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(ProtobufferCodec.PROTOBUFFER_ENCODED)
   String getData (@Body byte[] data);
}
```

The problem is, I need to send my bytes from my `byte[] data` param not changing the `@Consumes("application/x-protobuf")` in my Controller.

`body` is arriving as empty in the Controller.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a sample application somewhere I can look at?

Comment: Yes @JamesKleeh here is the test inside the app doing it: https://github.com/dcalap/micronaut-http-client/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/example/micronaut/ProtobufTest.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the current Protobuf codec only supports encoding Message types. See https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-grpc/blob/a00a348028628c170d74bd7267011255c9ac01cd/protobuff-support/src/main/java/io/micronaut/protobuf/codec/ProtobufferCodec.java#L157

It seems to me it should support raw `byte[]` as well. Please file an issue with https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-grpc and PRs are appreciated

Comment: Thanks a lot @JamesKleeh ! I've done it here https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-grpc/issues/6

Comment: Solved in new 1.0.1 version! :)